# Add OS/partition to encrypted disk using Logical Volume Manager, Debian 10 (Buster)

Tags: partition, luks, gparted, disk-encryption

I installed Debian 10, using the boot disk to encrypt the entire disk, and create a logical volume manager. Now I would like to install a completely separate instance of Debian. However, when I install GParted on a Debian 10 boot disk, GParted can not successfully make any changes. I had a friend who's rather experienced with Linux play around with it for two hours, and he concluded that the logical volume manager is to blame. He recommended I use [system-config-lvm](https://pkgs.org/download/system-config-lvm), but unfortunately Debian 10 is not supported. So I burnt a live DVD of Debian 9.12 (Stretch), ran system-config-lvm, and got the error "Unsupported LUKS version 2." I then tried to update lvm and was told it was running at the most recent version.

How can I add a partition (for a separate operating system) to this disk? 
Any utilities (or other distro's live DVD) I should try? 
Or do I just have to wipe the whole disk clean and start over?

*Per user "Emmanuel Rosa", here is the output of when I run lsblk on the Debian 10 live DVD:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0     2G  1 loop /usr/lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   243M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0   119G  0 part
sr0     11:0    1   2.2G  0 rom  /run/live/medium
```

Comment: Making space for an additional operating sytem is completed when using LVM because there are multiple layers which need to be resized: the filesystem(s), logical volume(s), physical volume, and finally the partition. It can be done, but again, it's complicated. Have you considered using a virtual machine, such as KVM?

Comment: I hadn't considered it, thanks for the suggestion. However, I'd still like to do it with just two separate Linux distros on two separate partitions. any resources you'd recommend for doing that (that I haven't already tried above?)

Comment: OK. Please boot the Debian 10 system and add the output of `lsblk` to your question.

Comment: Emmanual Rosa: I have added it. Please see above.

Comment: Is sda5 the LVM physical volume that needs to be resized to make room on the disk?

Comment: Yes. The computer has only around 120 GiB of storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are three things you need to resize, in the following order:

1. LVM logical volume(s) - Use `lvs` to see which volumes you have and `lvresize` to shrink them. Use the option which resizes the filesystem, to make things easier.
2. LVM physical volume - Use `pvresize` to shrink the physical volume within sda5.
3. Partition sda5 - Use `parted` to shrink the partition. But make sure you don't make it smaller than the physical volume (step 2 above)!

The exact command arguments will depend entirely on your specific situation, so I encourage you to read the man pages for the commands referenced above.

Comment: Yeah, or just keep the PV as is and make a new LV for the other instance of Debian.